# How do you create a method that finds the starting INDEX of the longest consecutive run in an array of boolean values in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, search

I am struggling with creating a method that loops through an array, finds the longest streak of values, and prints the starting index of that run of values. Any help would be appreciated. I specifically will be searching through an array of Boolean values, and I will be needing to find the longest streak of "true" values. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array and memorize what your state is. Then keep a counter and memorize how long your longest sequence is. If you have a longer sequence than the longest previously seen update the index.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] array = {true,false,false,true,true,true,true};
    int ix = 0;
    boolean condition = true;
    int longest = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
       if (condition!=array[i]){
           if (cnt > longest) {
                ix = i-cnt;
                longest = cnt;
           }
           condition = array[i];
           cnt = 0;
       }
       cnt++;

     }
     if (cnt > longest) {
        ix = array.length-cnt;
     }
     System.out.println(ix);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getLongestStreakIndex(boolean[] arr) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length == 0)
        return -1;

    int res = 0;

    for (int i = 1, j = 0, len = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i == arr.length - 1) {
            if (i - j + 1 > len)
                res = j;
        } else if (arr[i] != arr[i - 1] && i - j > len) {
            res = j;
            len = i - j;
            j = i;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```